# How to setup embeded Jetty to use JDBC sessions

Tags: session, jetty

I am using embedded jetty (group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-webapp', version: '9.4.27.v20200227') and I am trying to programmatically setup it to use JDBC for session storage. All the documentation/examples I can find is about standalone jetty.

Do you know how to setup it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know all that much about JDBC or session storage, but looking at the documentation [Persistent Sessions: JDBC](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-sessions-jdbc.html) for standalone jetty, it is telling you to enable the module `session-store-jdbc`. By looking at [`session-store-jdbc.mod`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/965483e4d9b4eac40478b28871f6d1e26d333034/jetty-server/src/main/config/modules/session-store-jdbc.mod) you can see that it uses [`etc/sessions/jdbc/session-store.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/965483e4d9b4eac40478b28871f6d1e26d333034/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/sessions/jdbc/session-store.xml) and these XML files can be directly translated into java code.

So it looks like its adding a `JDBCSessionDataStoreFactory` as a bean onto the server. So some equivalent code that you could try would look something like:

```java
// Configure a JDBCSessionDataStoreFactory.
JDBCSessionDataStoreFactory sessionDataStoreFactory = new JDBCSessionDataStoreFactory();
sessionDataStoreFactory.setGracePeriodSec(3600);
sessionDataStoreFactory.setSavePeriodSec(0);
sessionDataStoreFactory.setDatabaseAdaptor(...);

JDBCSessionDataStore.SessionTableSchema schema = new JDBCSessionDataStore.SessionTableSchema();
schema.setAccessTimeColumn("accessTime");
schema.setContextPathColumn("contextPath");
// ... more configuration here
sessionDataStoreFactory.setSessionTableSchema(schema);

// Add the SessionDataStoreFactory as a bean on the server.
server.addBean(sessionDataStoreFactory);
```

Comment: @Lachian I ended up using similar approach but I am not sure if it is "canonical" one. The worst thing is that there are no examples out there for setup via code, not XML. The tricky part here is `setDatabaseAdaptor()` where you have to give it DataStore. It should be pooled data source otherwise it becomes a bottleneck.